# How do gravitational waves carry energy when gravitational energy cannot be localised?

Tags: general-relativity, energy-conservation, gravitational-waves, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, linearized-theory

I have a very naive question, actually someone asked it and I can't answer. It simply asks that if gravitational energy cannot be localised (we cannot write a pure gravitational energy momentum tensor) then how do gravitational waves carry energy? I realised I do not understand gravitational waves well.

In addition, is it possible to directly find out the energy carried by gravitational waves when we do not have an energy momentum tensor for them?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose some matter A emits gravitational waves, and some matter B absorbs those waves, and the spacetime does not have further dynamics apart from this. In such a process the $0,0$ component of the energy momentum tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$ integrated over matter A goes down (in a LIF with A at rest) and the $0,0$ component of energy momentum tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$ integrated over matter B (in a LIF with B at rest) goes up. That is the sense in which gravitational waves carry energy. It is also the sense in which energy is conserved in general relativity.

There does not need to be a conservation overall if the spacetime has further dynamics, but in the case where it does not, the energy accounting is done via the non-linearity of the equations. It is something of a marvel that it all works out correctly.

In the weak gravity limit one can extract from the metric a quantity which acts in most respects like a stress-energy tensor for gravitational waves, as long as there is a clear separation of distance scales between the wavelength of the waves and the radius of curvature of the background spacetime on which the waves are propagating. This quantity involves averaging over a wavelength-sized region so it is not well-defined at a point. The suggestion is that the energy to be associated with the wave is owing to the curvature introduced by the wave.

Comment: Thanks. So in general the energy carried by GWs can only be estimated “indirectly”.

Comment: What you can estimate is the energy gained or lost by the matter. To associate this with the amount energy carried by GW is an extra assumption that is not really grounded in any facts. It might works in some cases.

Answer (score 5):

One can answer this on a few different levels but the bottom line is that energy is not conserved within general relativity.

Let me try to rephrase your question. On the right hand side of Einstein equation we have the so called stress-energy tensor $T_{\mu \nu}$ and naively one might expect it to include all the energy in some region. However, gravitational waves (GW) are a vacuum solution, that is we can have $T_{\mu \nu}=0$ even with the presence of GW. One can think of different ways out of this conundrum. One is simply to suppose GW have no energy. But we know a system can gain energy via GW. Another is to define a more general tensor for the energy that include also the "gravitational energy". This approach runs into technical difficulties which stem from the fact that a conservation law is expressed as covariant derivatives  $\nabla_\mu T_{\mu \nu}=0$ and these are zero for the metric.

So if we go back to your question "how do gravitational waves carry energy?", they simply do, but we might not understand what energy really is.

Comment: Thank you. As far as I understand, GWs can appear as solution to the linearised Einstein equations, where the background metric can just be Minkowski. But the fact that we have perturbations over $\eta_{ab}$ implies there is some matter/energy somewhere, isn't it? Secondly, the matter stress energy momentum tensor is covariantly conserved, as far as I know. Why then are you referring to partial derivatives?

Comment: Strictly speaking the existence of GW does not implies there is matter anywhere. We could have a completely empty universe but still GW would be a solution to the linearized Einstein equations. Moreover even if there is some source for the GW, it can be far away so we can have a large region with no matter but with GW,
Regarding your other comment you are right and I revised my answer. Let me just say that trying to define a conserved energy within general relativity is a rather deep and technical issue. I was trying to describe the gist of it and got it wrong. I hope it is better now.

Comment: Thank you again. When the Universe is strictly vacuum, why will GWs appear at all? Linearising Einstein equations means we are considering perturbations over the background metric which can be taken to be flat, upto the linear order. So, if there is no matter anywhere, why will these perturbations appear? Is that one considers quantum fluctuations even if classically there is no matter? On the second point, I remember reading somewhere on stackexchange that the energy momentum tensor for gravitation actually turns out to be the Einstein tensor.

Comment: It has nothing to do with quantum fluctuations and it is not really related to the flat background. It is a simple mathematical fact: I can set $T_{\mu \nu} = 0 $ everywhere and still find a metric with GW that solves Einstein equation. This does not answer why GW appear or where they came from, but it shows we can think of them independently of their source.
Yes, Einstein equation is $G_{\mu \nu} = T_{\mu \nu}$ where $G_{\mu \nu}$ is  the Einstein tensor.

Comment: Ok. This seems rather counter intuitive to me. Have to think about it.

Comment: It is similar to how people often talk about electromagnetic plane waves without mentioning a source. If it is unphysical, it isn't because it violates any law of physics. Just that it doesn't match the boundary conditions we see.

Comment: @mmesser314 I would say that in the EM case, when we talk about plane waves without mentioning a source, the understanding is that there is no source in the region of space and time I am looking at, but there is/was one outside that.